# Having issues with importing Pandas to Mu-editor

Tags: python, pandas, mu

"from pandas import *" is greeted with a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'" error message.

To write code in Python, I am currently used mu-editor which I access through the anaconda3 terminal.

I do have Python 3.9 installed and have run the command "pip install pandas" in the Command prompt (Windows 10). I was greeted with a warning messages saying " You are using pip version 21.2.3; however version 21.3.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the "path\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip" command.

This has been done as well, but I still cannot import the module.

Comment: Did you install pandas? `pip install pandas`

Comment: Yes, I refer to that in the third paragraph of OP